# Passing parameter with JSP to Controller in Spring

Tags: java, jsp

Hello im having a strugle with JSP and Spring,

```
<html>
<head>Title 
</head>
  <body>
       Welcome in my view
       <h1>Animal's Database</h1>
       <br>
       <strong>${message}</strong><br>Give me:<br>
       <a href="writeCat" >Cat's list</a><br>
       <a href="writeDog">Dog's list</a><br>
       <a href="writeSnake">Snake's list</a>

  </body>
```

and this is my controller

```
public String getAnimalList(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("animalList", animalDAO.getAnimalList("Cat"));
    return "list";
}
@RequestMapping("/writeDog")
public String getAnimalList1(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("animalList", animalDAO.getAnimalList("Dog"));
    return "list";
}
@RequestMapping("/writeSnake")
public String getAnimalList2(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("animalList", animalDAO.getAnimalList("Snake"));
    return "list";
}
```

what I'm trying to do is get rid of 3x `getAnimalList` method, but i cant figure it out, how to pass a string from JSP to controller eg. "Cat", "Snake", "Dog". 
I know that in the body of controller i should go with `request.getParameter(XXX).` The problem for me is making a jsp to send string value of corresponding animal to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the animal name string in path variable and for that url to access the rest service will become `basepath/write/animalName`,

```
@RequestMapping("/write/{animal}")
public String getAnimalList1(Model model, @PathVariable("animal") String animal){
    model.addAttribute("animalList", animalDAO.getAnimalList(animal));
    return "list";
}
```

With path variable you can add the name of animal in `href`,

```
<a href="/write/Cat" >Cat's list</a><br>
<a href="/write/Dog">Dog's list</a><br>
<a href="/write/Snake">Snake's list</a>
```

Comment: this was clear to me, but how it should be on jsp side?
     

         <a href="writeCat"  name="animal" value="Cat">Cat's list</a><br>

Comment: URL?animal=Cat&other=OtherIfYouWant

Comment: the URL after <a href="/write/Cat" >Cat's list</a><br> goes like this URL/writeCat (notice that "/" is missing) , so i changed @RequestMapping, but still wondering why it cuts out the "/" from the href URL